# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, FileStorage found

Tags: python, csv

I am getting the csv file from API like

```
fileobj = kwargs.get('csvfile')
with open(fileobj, "r") as f:

    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
```

and i am trying to read the file, but i am getting below error

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, FileStorage found
```

help me to how to read that csv file here

Comment: I think, the problem is `fileobj` is already an `open` file descriptor. Could you double check that ?

Answer (score 0):

Example with the simple file from disk:

**File**:

```
1,example.com/1,11
2,example.com/2,22
```

**Code**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
import contextlib
import csv

if __name__ == '__main__':

    res = dict()
    with contextlib.closing(open('file.csv', 'r')) as csv_file:
        reader_orig = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for el in reader_orig:
            id = el[0]
            res[id] = dict()
            res[id]['url'] = el[1]
            res[id]['tab'] = el[2]

print(json.dumps(res))
```

**Output**:

> {"1": {"url": "example.com/1", "tab": "11"}, "2": {"url": "example.com/2", "tab": "22"}}

In case your file stores in Web (the same file as in prev example):

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
import io
import csv
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':

    res = dict()

    reply = requests.get(url).text

    csv_file = io.StringIO(reply)
    reader_orig = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for el in reader_orig:
        id = el[0]
        res[id] = dict()
        res[id]['url'] = el[1]
        res[id]['tab'] = el[2]

    print(json.dumps(res))
```

Result the same as in prev example.

You need to change delimiter and maybe something else like encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is you are trying to `open` an already `opened file`,

```
>>> f = open('foo.csv', 'r')
>>> f
<open file 'foo.csv', mode 'r' at 0x7f2ca76d8660>
>>> open(f, 'r')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```